# Purple Screen with Ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, video

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 onto rack Workstations at work, and whenever I finish the install using CD I get a purple screen with these black lines running through them (as shown in the nice paint picture I made).

I have tried changing cables, ports I am plugged into, changed monitor, and also changed the GPU from AMD to Nvidea and I still get this issue! The thing is, this never use to happen even with the same exact disk. Anyone have any idea how to fix this or seen this issue before? I tried Google but have not found anything.

[image: Picture of the Issue]

Comment: What do you mean by " changed the GPU from AMD to Nvidea "? Did you physically replaced a GPU?

Comment: Yeah, I changed from a Radeon Pro to a Nvidea 3070 TI

Comment: Do you use any adapters to connect to a monitor. In many cases this is a problem. Maybe you'll have to manually set resolution. Also did you try 22.04?

Comment: Right now, no I am connected straight to the GPU with a display port cable. I have also tried HDMI, and also tried the VGA connection on the front of the workstation. Normally though these workstations are connected to a Matrix Switch using Xtron software. It is worth noting this is all in an air gapped internal network, so there is zero internet connection. I am downloading 22.04 onto my computer rn and then I am going to try that out today.